# Why am I not getting either letters from the courier after I'm already a Thane?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

Well, I downloaded Hearthfire, and I have done the quests of multiple Jarls. But I haven't gotten the two letters from the courier at all yet. I bought a house in Dragon's Reach, so I check all the time. Why am I not getting my letters?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try talking to the Jarl of Falkreath? Or Dawnstar? Or Morthal?

Even if you have completed quests for them in the past, if you want Hearthfire start, talk to them. On talking with them they will give you one more quest.

Hand in the quest to the Jarl, and you will get the letter.